# Is SaajSoapMessageFactory support Mtom resonse in Client side

Tags: spring, spring-ws, mtom, saaj

I am writing a Spring webservice Client which calls a SOAP service it return a SOAP response with attachment(MTOM->XOP include tag in Response).

In my current Client code i am using SaajSoapMessageFactory and injected the same in my WebServiceTemplate also I have set MtomEnabled to true in my marshaller.

With this setup when I call my SOAP service my client code can able to read SOAP response body but the attachment part in Response body is empty. For the same request in SOAP UI i can able to get attachment.

Is SaajSoapMessageFactory in Client side support MTOM response?

Comment: Maybe add some code showing how you are using WebServiceTemplate and how you are trying to get the attachment.

Comment: @AndreasVeithen I have updated my answer. Pls review and suggest if any other we can extract attachment

Answer (score 0):

I have extracted attachment with SaajSoapMessageFactory

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class MtomContentRespExtractor implements WebServiceMessageExtractor {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MtomContentRespExtractor.class);

    private JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
    private Class<MyContentResponse> responseType;

    public MtomContentRespExtractor(JAXBContext jaxbContext,
                       Class<MyContentResponse> responseType) {
        this.jaxbContext  = jaxbContext;
        this.responseType = responseType;

    }

    @Override
    public Object extractData(WebServiceMessage webServiceMsg) throws IOException, TransformerException {


        JAXBElement<MyContentResponse> jaxbElement = null;
        MyContentResponse myContResp = null;


        try {

            jaxbElement = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller()
                          .unmarshal(webServiceMsg.getPayloadSource(), responseType);

            Attachment attachment = (Attachment) ((SaajSoapMessage) webServiceMsg).getAttachments().next();
            myContResp =    (MyContentResponse) jaxbElement.getValue();
                        attachment.getInputStream()

            //Logic for response


        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }


        return myContResp;
    }
```